# How to refresh layout/context from list adapter (I think this is what i need)

Tags: java, android, layout

Im having a bug that i cant understand the reason and how to resolve it. I belive that is a problem of layout/view/context refresh but i dont know.

I have a cell from a listView(I prefer recyclerView but the project has years) and in the corner of the cell i have a button to show more options. Programatically it just make an element View.GONE and another element View.VISIBLE.

I will attach code in a moment

To this button i setted too a listener that when i tap on it it do the opposite of below mentioned. It shows some elements and hide an entire LinearLayout from the cell. The elements are showed BUT the LinearLayout keeps on the screen like bugged. If i tap anywhere it disappears and if i try to tap on it it disappears too. Its like the view of that linear got bugged and keep in there like a ghost view. I will shop some pictures.

The cell normally at the beginning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCmDu.jpg

The cell after i press the entire view to show the LinearLayout at the bottom of the cell: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wcKk.jpg

The cell after i press the arrow of the corner to hide the LinearLayout. Here it shows the view bugged https://i.stack.imgur.com/KziDQ.jpg

The cell after i tap anywhere else https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hejfb.jpg

```
public void expandView(View view){
    final View cellView = view;
    final LinearLayout editLinear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_edit);
    editLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final TextViewFont countText = (TextViewFont) view.findViewById(R.id.itemCount);
    countText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final TextViewFont total = (TextViewFont) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTotal);

    final ImageView imageViewArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_edit_image);
    imageViewArrow.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_arrow_up));
    //notifyDataSetChanged();
    imageViewArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            countText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageViewArrow.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_arrow_down));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to store context because in View you have the method view.getContext().
I recommend this article:
https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

On the other hand, ensure that you don't have a ghost view that is overlapping your image view.

Comment: I dont have any ghost view. It just stay there until i tap anywhere else. I thought that maybe is a refresh problem